# Eclipse ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator, adt

How do I upload media to local storage of emulator device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual use the [File Manager](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) inside your DDMS perspective.

Make it visible from <kbd>Eclipse</kbd> → <kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>Show View</kbd> → <kbd>File Explorer</kbd>.